# Unable to validate dreamspark account

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, account

We're currently trying to deploy our Windows Phone 7 app to a phone, and need to register a app hub developer account in the process. We all have Dreamspark accounts associated with the college we all go to, but somehow the site doesn't recognize our accounts when we try to register (https://users.create.msdn.com/Register).

Another option is to pay the $80 to get an account, but we'd rather avoid that extra cost when we should be able to register for free.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem before?

Comment: The App Hub developer signup page has "problems". Contact the helpdesk via links on the site and you may well be given a free 12 month token for signup. They did that for a paid account, so should even be easier for BizSpark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try logging in to your dreamspark  and when trying to register on the app hub? I did not have any problems validating my dreamspark account. Check your email once you have login to dream spark and trying to associate your account to apphub.

Answer (score 0):

Only registration @dreamspark is not sufficient..you will have to register yourself for publishing your app.Check out the link https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Windows-Phone-7-App-Development.aspx !Go to option3 and click the link to get registered